# Working with sets/lists between functions (python)

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm confused about how my program behaves when I work with sets between functions.

I have a few functions that modify a nested list: list1.

Imagine I have a 3x9 array, and position (0,0) has a set={6}, and the rest of the cells are sets `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

`def eliminateUnique(list1, (0,0), rowColBoxLocations`) takes a one value set, i.e. `{6}`, and pops it from all the sets in the same row, same column, and the same 3x3 box

Now when I run my code, it deletes the `{6}` from ALL rows and columns, and the array updates.

Now my question is, when this function updates the array, if there is no return list1,  (and I can't use global list1 as it's in the argument above), how do I get the updated list1 array into another function?

So if i call def solve(list1), and it calls `(list1, (0,0), rowColBoxLocations)`, how do I get the new list1 back to the solve function so I can further work on it? I think my eliminate function is not updating and passing the array to my solve function.

```
def main()
    list1=[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7], [3, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 9], 
          [1, 2, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3]]
    convertToSets(list1)
    eliminateUnique(list1,location, listOflocations)


def convertToSets(list1):
    s = set(range(1, 10))
    list1 = [[{j} if j!=0 else s for j in i] for i in list1]
    return list1

def eliminateUnique(list1, location, listOfLocations):
    count =0
    locVal = list1[location[0]][location[1]]
    if len(locVal)==1:
        lvint = list(locVal)[0] #integer value of number in set.
    for i in listOfLocations:
        if (lvint in list1[i[0]][i[1]]) and (i!=location):
            list1[i[0]][i[1]].remove(lvint)

def solve(list1) - here's where i'm having problems!
```

Added some code guys. main runs, calls `convertToSets`. 0->{1 to 9}, then passes it to `eliminateUniques`, and that's where I start having problems. `eliminateUnique` doesn't do what it is supposed to do when passing in a set. When I manually put the array inside the function, it seems fine. I think it might be to do with how I am using the sets.

Comment: lists in python are mutable, so when you pass a list to a function, the list gets changed everywhere. So, when you change this list in `eliminateUnique`, the list automatically changes in `solve`, so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Are you sure? for example I have:     
   'list1=read_sudoku(file)' ,' convertToSets(list1)", 'print(list1)',  and list1 originally is a list of lists, and the convert function changes it to nested list of sets, but when i print list1, it prints the list as if it wasn't changed, i.e. as nested list of integers. When i say: list1 = convertToSets(list1), only then does it change the original array of integers to an array of sets. I'm really confused by this.

Comment: sorry, I need the entire code of `convertToSets(list1)` to figure out why that happens, but the fact that you can say `list1 = convertToSets(list1)` means that that function is returning something, leading me to believe that something is going on inside there(don't have much to go on). BTW, use backticks around your inline code to highlight it

Comment: It would help if you post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the list doesn't change outside the function when you edit it inside the function, but the entire issue, as you said, can be circumvented by adding `return list1` at the end of `eliminateUnique` and then saying `list1 = convertToSets(list1)` and then `list1 = eliminateUnique(list1...`

Comment: Hi @notcompletelyrational Unfortunately for this assignment i'm not allowed to return the array using the return feature, and I can't make it global because of the arguments. Is there another way to ensure the array gets between functions?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to simply remove the `main()` function entirely, so that list1 becomes a global variable and then inside each of the functions, include `global list1` as the first line. Make sure you delete `list1` from the parameter list.

Comment: I think the function is pushing the problem function through but now I can't get my function to loop through "i"!     `for i in listoflocations:`
        `if (lvint in list1[i[0]][i[1]]) and (i!=location):` This only iterates through the first i. Can you see if anything in that looks wrong?

Comment: here's something interesting. When I isolate my function and put it into a separate page with a manually typed out array (as opposed to importing it from a file), it works fine. but as soon as I go back to my main program and run the same code on the same data (but importing it from a text file), the function doesn't give the same output. Any ideas why could be causing this @notcompletelyrational

Comment: I'm not sure about that! You might want to start a new question to keep things organized

Answer (score 0):

In the comments the point is made that lists are mutable.  The way that your function eliminateUniques() works takes advantage of that by modifying items inside the list via index values.

The reason that convertToSets() doesn't work that way is you are not modifying the list, you are creating a new one and assigning it to the local variable list1 having the same name as the parameter passed in.  You could create a temporary list2 with your original list comprehension and then do list1.clear() to empty the original list and then iterate over list2 and copy it to list1 by indexing eg: list1[0]=list2[0]  but really that's a lot of wasted work rather than using the returned value of the function as is.  So in main you would do list1 = convertToSets(list1)

Answer (score 0):

Here your create new local variable `list1` and return it:

```
def convertToSets(list1):
    s = set(range(1, 10))
    list1 = [[{j} if j!=0 else s for j in i] for i in list1]
    return list1
```

but you don't use the returned value and `convertToSets(list1)` has no effect on the outer `list1` whatsoever:

```
def main()
    list1=[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7], [3, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 9], 
          [1, 2, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3]]
    convertToSets(list1)
    eliminateUnique(list1,location, listOflocations)
```

Change your code to:

```
def main()
    list1=[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7], [3, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 9], 
          [1, 2, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3]]
    list1 = convertToSets(list1)
    eliminateUnique(list1,location, listOflocations)
```

The important part is:

```
    list1 = convertToSets(list1)
```

This assigned the returned value back to the name `list1` and this new list be used in `eliminateUnique(list1, location, listOflocations)`.